# maven resource plugin or packageExclude in war plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a (exploded) war file generated by maven. I want to exclude some directories from the packaging. So I tried it with the two following ways:

1. Way:

```xml
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>css/*.css</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

This does not work as expected. The plugin will copy all other files but the excluded above from my resource-directory (`src/main/webapp/resources/`) into the war-folder `src/main/resources`. I do not want to copy all the other files from `src/main/webapp/resources` to `src/main/resources`.  The `resource-plugin` should ONLY exclude the above files and should not additionally copy the other files from `src/main/webapp/resources` into `src/main/resources`. Is there a way to say that to the `resource-plugin`?

The second way, does also not work:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/css/*.css</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The debug output shows, that the path is correct:

```
[DEBUG]   (s) packagingExcludes = /Users/test/src/main/webapp/resources/css/*.css
```

However, looking in my exploded war-archive, the "css/*.css" are NOT excluded. What is wrong?

Comment: I found out that the second way will work, but only for the packaged war-archive. The exploded war contains the files which should be excluded.

Comment: By reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061627/maven-war-plugin-not-able-to-exlude-libs-in-exploded-war-format, i found out that exploded war archives do not make use of the packagingExcludes-settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution:

I have to use this

```
<configuration>
<warSourceExcludes>
...
</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
```

to exclude resources in the exploded war file.